# =GOOGLEFINANCE result value cannot be captured via getValue

Tags: google-sheets-api, countif, getvalue

Had tried to setup as below, but from script range(A1).getValues always get 
0 (should be 300.0) in debug mode, please help!

```
=GoogleFINANCE("APL","price")
 300.00
```

Comment: Is this Excel spreadsheet or another spreadsheet app? Please edit tags accordingly.

Comment: What code are you using? Maybe, you want to see [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android) for further reference. You can see there how the **`getValues()`** was implemented.